# How to convert this jQuery 1.7.1 on listener to jQuery 3.1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code that works using jQuery 1.7.1

```
$j('#manager-result').on('click','.myLi',function(){
    $j('#manager-search').val($(this).text());
    $j('#assignedmanager').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

The DOM:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="manager-search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for manager...">
<ul class="livesearch" id="manager-result" onclick="clickResult()"></ul>
```

The results of the livesearch:

```
<li data-value="liValue" class="myLi">
<small>nameString functionString</small>
</li>
```

Now when I use jQuery 3.1.1 it stops functioning. Currently I still link to it using the No Conflict mode but I want to eliminate the dependence on it altogether. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Signature for `on()` hasn't changed. Something else is different or causing problems. What errors are thrown? Where have you defined `$j`?

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-iBcUE/x23aI6syuqF7EeT/+JFBxjPs5zeFJEXxumwb0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>` It works perfectly using $j though.

Comment: did you include the `noConflict()` when you switched? Errors?? Confused when you say it works but question says it doesn't

Comment: I already tried removing it when I switched. What I meant to say was that it works if jQuery 1.7.1 is called using the no confict setting. If I use jQuery 3.1.1 it stops working.

Comment: so just use `$` instead of `$j`. If you have a lot of code with `$j` keep noConflict...won't hurt anything but means you always have to use `$j` not `$`